Gradio app works fine using simple Dockerfile, but fails when using docker-compose
I have a simple gradio app that runs fine inside Docker, but fails when launched via docker-compose.
app.py
import gradio as gr


def greet(name):
    return f"Hello {name}!"


iface = gr.Interface(fn=greet, inputs="text", outputs="text")
iface.launch(server_name="0.0.0.0", server_port=7860)

Dockerfile
FROM python:3.12-slim

WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

ENV GRADIO_SERVER_PORT=7860
ENV GRADIO_SERVER_NAME=0.0.0.0
EXPOSE 7860

CMD ["python", "app.py"]

I created then Dockerfile, and built it using docker build -t my_gradio .
Then launched it using docker run -p 7860:7860 -e GRADIO_SERVER_NAME="0.0.0.0" my_gradio
So far so good; I can access the gradio UI on localhost:7860
docker-compose.yaml
services:  
  my_gradio:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "7860:7860"
    networks:
      - net
    environment:
      - GRADIO_SERVER_NAME="0.0.0.0"
      - GRADIO_SERVER_PORT=7860

networks:
  net:

When I run this docker-compose.yaml file, I get an error
Attaching to my_gradio-1
my_gradio-1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
my_gradio-1  |   File "/app/app.py", line 9, in <module>
my_gradio-1  |     iface.launch(server_name="0.0.0.0", server_port=7860)
my_gradio-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gradio/blocks.py", line 2368, in launch
my_gradio-1  |     ) = http_server.start_server(
my_gradio-1  |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
my_gradio-1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gradio/http_server.py", line 154, in start_server
my_gradio-1  |     raise OSError(
my_gradio-1  | OSError: Cannot find empty port in range: 7860-7860. You can specify a different port by setting the GRADIO_SERVER_PORT environment variable or passing the `server_port` parameter to `launch()`.
my_gradio-1 exited with code 1

I launched it using
docker compose -f docker-compose.yaml  up --build
requirements.txt
gradio

I do not understand what is the problem ! The app works fine using simple Dockerfile, but does not work when using docker-compose.
I tried changing the port, setting a range of ports and still get the same problem !
Please help !

There's extra double quotes in the GRADIO_SERVER_NAME setting, and in the Compose syntax it's possible these are getting included in the environment variable value the application sees.  Does deleting these quotes help?

I have never thought that docker-compose treats double-quotes differelently.
You were right :) Thank you very much !

docker-compose.yml
services:
  my_gradio:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "7860:7860"
    networks:
      - net
    environment:
      - GRADIO_SERVER_NAME=0.0.0.0
      - GRADIO_SERVER_PORT=7860

networks:
  net:


i tested in my machine and as per the comment removing the double quote from GRADIO_SERVER_NAME value worked fine and the app was running fine with docker compose.

browser:

